# Sharepoint error 403 access forbidden

Tags: iis, sharepoint, http-status-code-403

I am new to sharepoint and after creating a new web application this is what i'm getting -

The website declined to show this webpage 
 HTTP 403
   Most likely causes:
•This website requires you to log in.

This error (HTTP 403 Forbidden) means that Internet Explorer was able to connect to the website, but it does not have permission to view the webpage.

I have Anonymous Authorization enabled in IIS and in sharepoint central admin.
Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the NTFS security permissions on that object (folder/file)
2. Run "Filemon" (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) on the sharepoint server to find out which AD Object (user/group) are having issues accessing/serving the file.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this when the account that acts as the identity for the app pool connected to your SharePoint site is not in the correct groups. Figure out which user is the app pool identity, then add it to the following groups in Computer Management:

- WSS_ADMIN_WPG
- WSS_WPG
- Administrators

Answer (score 0):

we had the same issue. everything was working fine in the morning, by the afternoon users started receiving 403 Forbidden messages. The Central Administration site was also not accessible with the same error.

It is a cause for concerning as to what fixed it though - an IIS reset!!! CPU usage was not high, memory usage was not high. Just pure Microsoft technology being Microsoft technology. Atleast it was an easy fix, even though we have no clue what caused it.